# Квадратные thumbnails из не квадратных изображений?

Tags: javascript, изображения, thumbnails, php, css

Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста куда копать? Проблема заключается вот в чем:

Есть фотографии из соц сетей (вконтакте, инстаграм например). Изображения вытаскиваются из `api`, и обычно в ответе от `api` присутствует `thumbnail` фотографии (`src_small` к примеру). В случае с инстаграмом всё отлично - там по дефолту **квадратные** изображения. В случае с остальными соц сетями - изображения там какие попадутся.

Так вот в чем вопрос: возможно ли средствами css отображать только квадратную область изображения ? Просто обрезать на сервере - довольно трудозатратная операция, если фотографии будут грузиться пачками по 20 (например). И если будет много пользователей делать это одновременно, страшно подумать что случится с моим дешевым хостингом (а пока вообще бесплатным) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Осмелюсь как вариант предложить такой индусский код: http://jsfiddle.net/ptEy8/

Но очень хотелось бы увидеть ещё варианты! Хороший вопрос.

Comment: О боже, это работает :) Спасибо гигантское :)

Comment: Я сделал crop на сервере just for fun, интересно замерить - как будет нагружаться сервер) по сути - изображения небольшие ~100px в ширину, и кропает он их довольно быстро)

Comment: Вообще идеально было бы:

- задать height и width картинки от родителя в 110%;

- отцентровать ровно по середине;

- задать родителю overflow: hidden;

Comment: Вот будет лучше, мне кажется: http://jsfiddle.net/SDesN/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pechenushka/SDesN/1/

во втором случае изображение искажается) а в 1м отображает как раз то что нужно)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GgKme/

всё таки этот способ мне нравится больше ;)

Comment: Соглашусь с тем, что он более "честный" :) Но возникает вот что http://jsfiddle.net/pechenushka/GgKme/1/ :) в первом случае нас спасает background-position: center; .. А здесь опять придется извертеться :)